# My reputation was decreased when I down-voted spam answers

Tags: support, voting, spam

I saw two questions with spam answers; I have down-voted these answers, and I saw that my reputation has been decreased. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get a -1 for downvotes. If it is spam, flag it; don't down-vote it.

[image: screenshot]